# C++ Builder include header file from other folder

Tags: c++builder

I'm using C++Builder.  I want to include a header file that is located in a separate folder from my project.

I tried to add the folder to the search path, and include the file in my project:

```
#include "GXWARE32\Include\gxutils.h"
```

but when I compile I have some errors in the file included

[image: Errors while compiling]

So, I tried to add all subfolders to the search path, and it works with a small folder but not with a big one.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error log, maybe you missed some header file that `gxutils.h` relies on.

Answer (score 0):

Without code, we can only guess... some libs need a specific `#include` order... some libs have hard-coded relative paths and by moving them you broke that... Some libs also need configuration macros defined before `#include`.

From the errors, you have `#include`'d some file more than once (and it's not protected by a header guard, like `#pragma once` or `#ifndef file_id #define file_id ... #endif` macros) and you are missing a previous `#include` for some datatype used.

Open the `gxutils.h` file and look around line 143 for the missing datatype. In the IDE, during compilation the cursor usually stops on the stuff directly. Then just search the files in your lib for the datatype, so you know what file to `#include` before...

All of these might happen sometimes if you include the wrong file... some libs need to include `cpp` instead of `h`...

Adding search paths will not do anything as the compiler is not complaining about files not found...